# Ubuntu libraries problem

Tags: bash, libraries, compile, make

I already asked this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196634/android-build-failure), but it seems like the problem is probably with linker.

So, the question is:

I'm trying to build a project, using `$ make`, but it fails:

```
host SharedLib: libneo_cgi (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so) 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.a when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so] Error 1
```

Now look at this library:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libz.so 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 2010-07-07 17:08 /usr/lib/libz.so -> /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3

$ file /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

and I have:

```
$ arch
i686
```

I installed this library like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

So.. How do I get through this? And how do I make Ubuntu download right libs in the future? And I'm actually not sure: is this the real problem, or it is somewhere else?

I'm also unable to install some required packages:

```
E: Couldn't find package lib32z1-dev
E: Couldn't find package lib32ncurses5-dev
```

P.S. Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, running on Lenovo ThinkPad SL500, Core 2 DUO CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that I've resolved this problem. I replaced my jdk6 with sun-jdk5 (added Jaunty's repo) and replaced my default jdk6 with it:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.5.0-sun
```

I've left my laptop compiling for the weekend, and now it seems, that it succeeded.

Comment: Really? this still did not solved my case.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same issue on my Lenovo Netbook s10e Intel Atom running Ubuntu 10.04 netbook edition. After countless hours of searching the net for answers I hear this has something to Java6 checking and forcing a 64 bit build in Clearsilver for 32bit systems. The solution was to roll back the clearsilver path located here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/clearsilver.git;a=commitdiff;h=d36910a8110d8377b22301274d2b5131a732a72b

unfortunately i am not sure how exactly to do this. i used the abandon feature in repo to remove those .mk links listed but it did not change the error.

would really appreciate some help.

Comment: just found some helpful information on this issue here:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/compile-problem-818890/

Comment: You found more threads by the OP, actually. But forcing -m64 -> broken build process.

Comment: yeah, that's my question on LQ :)
But there's no solution in that thread neither.

Answer (score 0):

The Canonical (not "canonical") package names for Lucid Lynx are `zlib1g-dev` and `libncurses5`.

Just curious, did you invent the name `libz-dev` or did some documentation lead you to that?

Comment: My system cannot find those two. But it can fing `libz-dev`, so..

Answer (score 0):

Your system seems in order, but the build process could be broken. Does make tell you the command it uses to build?